# Ansible sum register value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How to get the sum of two hosts with Jinja2 filtering ansible
host1 and host 2

```
---
- name: Count Check
  hosts: MYGROUP
  gather_facts: true
  user: sv_admin
  tasks:
    - name: count check
      shell: cat /etc/hosts | wc -l
      register: command_result
    - debug:
        var: command_result.stdout
    - set_fact:
        total_result: "{{ command_result.stdout | map('int') | sum(start=0) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Total count: {{ total_result }}"
```

Playbook Output

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [Host-01] => {
  "msg": "Total count:      134"
}
ok: [Host-02] => {
  "msg": "Total count:      133"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom stats to do that: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_stats_module.html

So for your case it would look like

```yaml
---
- name: Count Check
  hosts: MYGROUP
  gather_facts: true
  user: sv_admin
  tasks:
    - name: count check
      shell: cat /etc/hosts | wc -l
      register: command_result
    - debug:
        var: command_result.stdout
    - set_fact:
        host_result: "{{ command_result.stdout }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Count for this host: {{ host_result }}"
    - set_stats:
        data: "{{ { 'total_count': host_result | int } }}"
```

Then if you run it with `ANSIBLE_SHOW_CUSTOM_STATS=yes` it will show you the result at the end:

```
$ ANSIBLE_SHOW_CUSTOM_STATS=yes ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml
... (usual output)

CUSTOM STATS: *************************************************************

    RUN: { "total_count": 267}
```

The `set_stats` task adds results together from all the hosts by default, which is what you are looking for. You need to make sure the values are integers though, because if they are strings it will just concatenate them and you will end up with something like `RUN: { "total_count": "134133"}`. That's why I have put the `data:` bit the way I have - if you try to create the dictionary in regular yaml, like

```yaml
  data:
    total_count: "{{ host_result | int }}"
```

you will see that the value is still a string (due to the way yaml/jinja works) and it won't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) and [sum](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#sum). For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01:test_03
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: cat /etc/hosts | wc -l
      register: command_result
    - debug:
        var: command_result.stdout
    - set_fact:
        total_result: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                          map('extract', hostvars, ['command_result', 'stdout'])|
                          map('int')|
                          sum }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: total_result
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [test_01:test_03] ****

TASK [shell] ****
changed: [test_01]
changed: [test_03]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [test_01] => {
    "command_result.stdout": "      62"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "command_result.stdout": "      31"
}

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [test_03] => {
    "total_result": "93"
}
ok: [test_01] => {
    "total_result": "93"
}
```

---

- See [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)
- See the difference between [ansible_play_hosts and ansible_play_hosts_all](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)